# WCF: Returning a complex object in JSON format

Tags: json, wcf, complextype

I'm writing a WCF web service which return data as JSON.

This has been working fine, but I wish to return a list of objects, each of which will contain another list of objects.

This results in no data being sent to the client.

How do I serialize this list of complex objects and return it as JSON.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Vinod, I already have the custom class.  The problem is now to return these lists from the service.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom class and with in the custom class you can create some properties with list datatype and return the list of custom class from service method. the below will code helps you

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Get", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
List<StoreAndProductDetails> UpdateStoreProductPriceList();

public class StoreAndProductDetails
{
    public StoreAndProductDetails();

    public List<PriceFeed> listPriceFeed { get; set; }
    public List<ProductFeed> listProductFeed { get; set; }
    public List<StoreFeed> listStoreFeed { get; set; }
}
```